# How can I exclude products based on status in Python and Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Let's say I have the following Pandas DataFrame with product descriptions.
How can I exclude every product (`id`) that has a `status` other than 4,5 or 6?

**input:**

```
    id | description | status
    -------------------------
    1  | world1      | 1
    1  | world2      | 4
    1  | world3      | 1
    1  | world4      | 4
    1  | world5      | 4
    1  | world6      | 4
    1  | world7      | 1
    1  | world8      | 4
    1  | world9      | 4
    1  | world10     | 4
    1  | world11     | 4
    1  | world12     | 4
    1  | world13     | 4
    1  | world14     | 4
    1  | world15     | 1
    2  | world1      | 4
    2  | world2      | 4
    2  | world3      | 5
    2  | world15     | 6
    2  | world8      | 6
    2  | world4      | 5
    2  | world7      | 5
```

**output:**

```
    id | description | status
    -------------------------
    2  | world1      | 4
    2  | world2      | 4
    2  | world3      | 5
    2  | world15     | 6
    2  | world8      | 6
    2  | world4      | 5
    2  | world7      | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter all `id` which contains another values from `list` and then filter all `id` which not contains `a` values:

```
L = [4,5,6]
a = df.loc[~df['status'].isin(L), 'id']
df = df[~df['id'].isin(a)]
print (df)
    id description  status
15   2      world1       4
16   2      world2       4
17   2      world3       5
18   2     world15       6
19   2      world8       6
20   2      world4       5
21   2      world7       5
```

Detail:

```
print (a)
0     1
2     1
6     1
14    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000

L = np.random.randint(1000,size=N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'status': np.random.choice([4,5,6,7], p = (0.3,0.3,0.39,0.01), size=N),
                   'id':np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'description':np.random.choice(L, N)})
print (df)


L = [4,5,6]

In [461]: %%timeit 
     ...: a = df.loc[~df['status'].isin(L), 'id']
     ...: df[~df['id'].isin(a)]
     ...: 
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop

#Wen's solution
In [462]: %%timeit
     ...: df['status']=df['status'].mask(~df['status'].isin([4,5,6]))
     ...: df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x : ~x.status.isnull().any() )
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 111 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! Unfortunately I cant upvote your answer because I’m a newbie :(. I will upvote it as soon as I have the rights. Upvoting my question will help me upvoting you ;)

Comment: You are welcome! I already upvote your question, see [here](https://snag.gy/lFXy8P.jpg) - there is orange color of `0`.

Comment: Hey @jezrael, could you maybe also take a look at my other question, since you are a boss? :) I have been trying for days now. Still no progress: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461149/filtering-products-based-on-description-scenarios-and-status-in-python-pandas

Comment: I check it tomorrow, sorry I forget check comment. Now I am on phone only.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps

1st Using `mask`

```
df['status']=df['status'].mask(~df['status'].isin([4,5,6]))
```

2nd `groupby` +`filter`

```
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x : ~x.status.isnull().any() )
Out[44]: 
    id description  status
15   2      world1     4.0
16   2      world2     4.0
17   2      world3     5.0
18   2     world15     6.0
19   2      world8     6.0
20   2      world4     5.0
21   2      world7     5.0
```